# Comparing if *.csr and *.pem files match

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, pki

Since I wasn't familiar with generating keys and certificates, I had some testing to do at the time. Now I feel that a certain pair might have been mixed up.

I have one RSA Private key file:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
             ...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

and the certificate signing request file sent to the other party:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
              ...
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

Whilst trying to check the match, with information found on the Web, it might be worth noting that the following:

```
openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in cert.csr | openssl md5
```

Gives the following error:

```
unable to load certificate
4980:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:.\crypto\pem\pem_lib.c:650:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
```

Although it still gives me and md5 hash. Running a similar command on the private key produces another md5. Since these don't match, can I assume now, that the csr was not generated from the key?

I was able to check the stored values in the csr with the following command:

```
openssl req -in cert.csr -noout -text
```

I tried generating a new one with the same values. This did not give me the exact same result - only the first three lines were the same.

**Is there a way to check if the csr and pem files really match or there has been a mixup?**

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/), [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out, since I didn't find a suitable answer on the web myself and in case anyone else needs it... Might not be the best way, but at least gave the desired result.

I ran two commands. This one on the private key file:

```
openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in key.pem
```

The following on the certificate:

```
openssl req -noout -modulus -in cert.csr
```

If the outputs matched, the key and certificate matched.

Found the correct private key and was able to restore the correct one from the repository.

Comment: A Certificate binds a key to an identity. The identity is represented by the distinguished name. So I'm fairly certain both the *Subject Distinguished Name* and *Public Key* needs to match.

Answer (score 2):

Run these command in linux box and validate whether their md5 values are equal.

```
$ openssl rsa -noout -modulus -in key.pem | openssl md5
```

```
$ openssl req -noout -modulus -in key.csr | openssl md5
```

```
$ openssl x509 -noout -modulus -in key.crt | openssl md5
```